# Change value of grid item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have table:

[image]

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add</legend>
        <br />
        @{ 
    var grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.produkty,null, "names", 5);
              }
@grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "head",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
          grid.Column("name"),
           grid.Column("value"),
           grid.Column(header: "Add", format: (item) =>
                        new HtmlString(
                                Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.add).ToString())),
           grid.Column( header: "Ok", format: (item) =>
                new HtmlString(
                        Html.ActionLink("OK", "add_method", new { ID_name = item.ID_name }).ToString()))         

            )
        )


    </fieldset>
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult use()
            {
                var nam = (from d in baza.Names
                            select new { d.ID_name, d.name, d.value}).ToList();



                ViewBag.names= nam;
                return View();
            }

   public ActionResult add_method(int ID_name, useModel use)
            {
                Use us = new Use();
                var dat = DateTime.Today;

                us.value = use.add;
                us.ID_Name= ID_name;
                us.data = dat;

                baza.Zuzycies.InsertOnSubmit(us);
                baza.SubmitChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("use", "Product");
            }
```

Model:

```
public class useModel
    {
        public int ID_name{ get; set; }
        public decimal value{get;set;}
        public string date { get; set; }

    }
```

So, I have list of product on page. And I want to add a value (amount of product)  into TextBox and press a ActionLink "OK" next to the textbox. How can I get amount of product in add_method? Or how insert submit button next to every one product (instead ActionLink "OK"), then is enought make use POST method...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grid componet with built-in edits functions (like the [telerik Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingajax)).
I think it's better to use ajax not reagular post request for your scenario.

Or you can do that ajax calls to the server with jquery, just send the parameters to the controller.

Comment: I don't wont just edit/change the amount of product, I need too, save to database what I changed... so edit function isn't good. I don't now ho to do it using ajax or jquery.. I never used them. I read some about that, and have question. If make submit funkction in ajax, I will stay on the same page, and will change just value,(dynamic page), yes? If yes, how add record to database, what I changed, using ajax? Or ajax can redirect me to other view/controller method, and get, and put into another controller ID and value(from TextBox).

Comment: @user1031034, look at the demo. You can do in the server what ever you want. (I can't teach jquery in the comments, just google for jquery ajax example)

Comment: The only solution is jQuerry ?

Comment: @Misi. No, you can send ajax requests with vainilla javascript as well.